# proguard parse exception in android.txt file

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am getting this exception.

```
proguard.ParseException: Expecting opening '(' or separator ';' before '=' in line 48 of file 'D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717\sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt',
```

and line 47 -56 is below

```
-keepclassmembers class com.sec.svoice.api.SVoice {
    private java.lang.long interface_handle = -1L;
    private java.lang.long sentinel_handle = -1L;
    private java.lang.String host;
    private java.lang.int port;
    private java.lang.String deviceId;
    public static final java.lang.int SP_ASR = 1;
    public static final java.lang.int SP_NLU = 2;
    static final java.lang.int[] seed;
}
```

Comment: no need of assignment .worked after removing assignment from variable.

Comment: Answer your own question (put the comment above as an answer) and accept it, this way it will be more useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need of assignment .worked after removing assignment from variable

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming most of these fields are actually primitives, the proper syntax is:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.sec.svoice.api.SVoice {
    private long interface_handle;
    private long sentinel_handle;
    private java.lang.String host;
    private int port;
    private java.lang.String deviceId;
    public static final int SP_ASR;
    public static final int SP_NLU;
    static final int[] seed;
}
```

You can leave out the modifiers if you wish:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.sec.svoice.api.SVoice {
    long interface_handle;
    long sentinel_handle;
    java.lang.String host;
    int port;
    java.lang.String deviceId;
    int SP_ASR;
    int SP_NLU;
    int[] seed;
}
```

If these are all the fields, you can use a wildcard:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.sec.svoice.api.SVoice {
    <fields>;
}
```

If you're preserving the fields for serialization purposes, you probably only need the non-static fields:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.sec.svoice.api.SVoice {
    !static <fields>;
}
```